# Can a complex magnetic field deflect a proton using a smaller Larmor orbit than a laminar field of similar intensity?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

I heard this in a lecture. I was hoping someone can provide a reference that I can cite.

To deflect a proton, the proton must be able to complete its larmor orbit. But if we have a fluctuating field lines (complex), the proton would require a smaller overall distance to be deflected when compared to a laminar field of similar intensity.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you compare the two cases? What does it mean for an arbitrarily-fluctuating field to have a "similar intensity" to a "laminar" (I assume you mean constant) field?

Comment: @probably_someone the average intensity over some time interval